# JDBC select query returns wrong values

Tags: sql, select, jdbc

I was performing **JDBC** select query in my web service to return some values from my database. Part of this table is attached to this question. After performing following query:

```
SELECT * FROM uses WHERE  uses_user_fk='22';
```

I receive only one row, but in database are two values that meet the query conditions, as you can see in attached picture. Can anyone tell me where I made a mistake. I’m using following JDBC instruction to execute the query

```
ResultSet tempResultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

Bellow image of database table **uses**:
[image]

Below the compete method that query the database, argument query is the same as listed earlier “**SELECT * FROM uses…**”. I should add that the  answer for that query is **4**, I also try this query without using quotes **(uses_user_fk=22**) but the result was the same:

```
protected ArrayList<Integer> queryForIds(String query, String column) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connect = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(GeneralDatabaseConstants.DATABASE_CONNECTION_URL);
            statement = connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet tempResultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
            if (tempResultSet.next())
                ids.add(new Integer(tempResultSet.getInt(column)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            close();
        }
        return ids;
    }
```

Comment: Show your java code please. Maybe you used an `if` instead of `while`

Comment: You'll have to show the code that makes you think you're only getting back one row.

Comment: close your client tool and run again.

Comment: How to get result by ResultSet? post your code.

Comment: Please show both your code and your schema definition.

Comment: Btw: if `uses_user_fk` is a *numeric* column you should not use a string value to compare against it. Use `uses_user_fk=22` instead (note the number literal instead of the character literal)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, i will change it, and remember it for future cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
if (tempResultSet.next())
```

with

```
while (tempResultSet.next())
```

Comment: I don’t know how I could miss it. Shame on me.